# vim gets stuck at top or bottom

Tags: vim

When I scroll to the top or bottom of a document using a pressed <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd>, vim temporarily gets stuck (around one second) as if it has to finish clearing the keyboard buffer. Can I correct this issue somehow?
I know G or gg is faster most of the time but sometimes I'm close to the top or bottom anyways.

I use console vim version "VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan 14 2015 20:14:49)" for Arch Linux.

Comment: You're flooding Vim with what is sometimes called a typeahead buffer. There's no way to interrupt Vim from processing that, because any key you press will only go into the "end" of the queue.

Comment: WHy are you scrolling up to the top or bottom with j or k? Why not use gg or G instead?

Comment: I use gg or G if it's far away but if it is just 5 lines then I feel that is faster but maybe I really should retrain and always use that.